# To what extent would a civil court defer to a criminal court (jury) decision?

Tags: criminal-law, civil-law, burden-of-proof

To what extent does the doctrine of *stare decisis* bind civil courts to the decisions, especially the jury determinations, of criminal courts?

If someone was convicted of an act that was both a crime and a tort, (fraud, for example), and was afterwards sued for fraud, to what extent (if any) is the criminal court's determination (to a standard of "beyond all reasonable doubt) binding on the civil court trying the same person for the same instance of the same offense, to a standard of "on the balance of probabilities"?

Comment: Briefly, not at all: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/15004. The effect is implemented through collateral estoppel.

Comment: See, e.g. The People of the State of California v. Orenthal James Simpson & and the civil suits brought against OJ by the Brown and Goldman families.